# WebSphere MQ v7 binding support for Redhat Linux

Tags: linux, ibm-mq

Am trying to integrate a J2EE application running on Weblogic 10.3 with WebSphere MQ V7, both running on Redhat Linux Enterprise 5.5 (on the same machine 64 bit Intel Architecture). MDB deployed as part of the application is not able to connect to the WebSphere MQ Queue using binding mode. Same configuration works on Solaris and WL 10.0. Can anyone please confirm if binding mode is supported on the mentioned configuration? Read some old articles that said binding is not supported on Linux for MQ 5.

Comment: An error stack trace would help. Are MQ libraries present, so WL can find them?

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely supported.  It is controlled by the `TRANSPORT` attribute of the connection factory.  See *[Properties of objects](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm10910_.htm)* for details of this attribute.

If I had to guess, your ConnectionFactory has parameters for host, port or channel and/or has `TRANSPORT` set to something other than `BIND`.

My second guess would be that the application is not authorized to connect.  By default, any IDs not in the mqm group have no access and a group that the ID belongs to must be granted authorization using the `setmqaut` command.

Without knowing the reason code returned when you are trying to connect, these are just guesses.  Can you print the stack trace and, most important of all, the linked exception?